# azure static web app - how to access site files? We lost the git repo

Tags: azure, git

we have a devops git repo connected to our static webapp, which auto deploys when the repo changes.

However, the dev-ops git repo is now somehow empty (like it was never created).  Is there any way to view or export all the files on the static web app?  We cant see any options in azure portal

Answer (score 0):

Locate the **Storage Account** where your static web app was created. In the left menu, select **Storage Explorer**.  Under then **Blob Containers** section, select **$web**. You'll see the files and you'll be able to download them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I cant see anything storage account related in the static web app.   There is a "source" link, but this goes to our devops git rep with "repository not found".  Looks like we somehow deleted the git repo.

Comment: I can confirm that I don't see a storage account related to the static web app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and found this answer from Microsoft:

> In static webapps you cannot find the output files of the build and
> all the output files generated will be managed by the platform only as
> per the By-design

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1045337/where-are-azure-static-web-app-files-located